# raise x to y where y is negative and with decimals

Tags: r, exp

This gives an error:

```r
X <- -3.3
Y <- -2.2
X^Y  ## NaN
```

Am I wrong? Is it not possible to raise a value to a negative decimal value?

Comment: I guess you'll need to cast (or initialize) x and/or y to a complex number first, since the result is a complex number.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Post the code *itself* as (properly formatted) text. See the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
complex(real = x, imaginary = 0) ^ y
[1] 0.05850958-0.0425097i
```

As suggested by @9769953

Comment: Okay thank you.  That worked

Comment: Or if you like shortcuts, `(x+0i)^y`. @user3357510, if the answer worked for you then please click the check-mark to accept it ...

Answer (score 0):

@Clemsang's answer with `complex(...)` is fine, but you can also do this more compactly via `(X+0i)^Y`; because R's parser recognizes `<number>i` as an imaginary value, adding `0i` to a numeric quantity makes it complex-valued with `Im(.) == 0`.